# Load PostGIS Layer with BLOB and use the form widget for binary fields (QGIS 3.6) not working

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have tried to load a PostGIS layer containing a binary data field (BLOB, bytea) and then use the new form widget for binary fields (https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog36/index.html#feature-new-form-widget-for-binary-blob-fields). The problem is, that the binary field will not be in the layers attribute table, so the widget can not be used/activated. In the QGIS database manager the field is visible in the table preview. Does anybody knows what is going wrong or what I am missing?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QGIS (as of version 3.8.0) has no support for binary/bytea fields from Postgres sources. As of version 3.8, they are only supported for disk-based vector layers and in-memory scratch layers.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible in QGIS 3.16 (not tested on previous versions).

You can add a `bytea` column to your layer and QGIS is able to insert and retrieve the BLOB (if using PostgreSQL).

In the following use case, I added a `photo bytea` column to my layer to store images.

To configure the feature form, please follow the [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/385918/7348) to create either and HTML Widget or QML Widget to see your picture.

Your bytea field will became a Binary Widget and you can use it to upload your binary data.

If you use images, add an **HTML Widget** or **QML Widget** to the feature form to display the image, as shown below.

[image]

If you use other types of binary data, you have to customize the widgets.

Tested with Geopackage and PostgreSQL providers.

Comment: Also works with MS SQL.